# Can't see an added class

Tags: asp.net

I created an ASP.Net project in .Net 2.0 and uploaded all files to the server (dlls and cs files) to the server. It is a very basic HTML page with a button on it.
When I loaded it on the server, it was okay.

I added a **static** class to my project and used it when the button was clicked:

```
 protected void btnUse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtData.Text))
        Utils.SaveData(txtData.Text);
    }
```

When I uploaded it, I get the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Compilation Error Description: An
>   error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to
>   service this request. Please review the following specific error
>   details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Utils' does not exist in the
>   current context

What else should I upload?

Comment: Is this a "web application" project or a "web site" project?  (That is, do you have to compile the code in the IDE before changes take effect?)  What namespace is the page class in and what namespace is the `Utils` class in?

Comment: It is an ASP.NET Web Froms Application. The namespace is the same in all classes.

Comment: It is aspx.cs and Utils.cs is marked with Compile. I don't see any App_Code folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code change can't take effect until the code is compiled, and the result is the `.dll` file(s).  So two things to take care of here:

1. In order to add the class, you need to add it to the source code (which you've done), *re-compile* into the `.dll`s, and upload the new `.dll`s to the server.
2. You don't need (and shouldn't have) the `.cs` files on the server.  That's the source code, not the compiled result.  The compiled result is the `.dll`s.  The server needs those, the markup pages (`.aspx`, `.ascx`, etc.), and any other resources (images, JavaScript files, `.css` files, etc.), but not the C# source code.

Comment: It seems that all the compile is done on the server based on the cs files I upload. Is it normal?

Comment: That's usually a key difference between a "site" and an "application."  A "site" dynamically compiles when a change is detected in a file, whereas an application is pre-compiled before deployment.

Comment: Then it can be said that this is a site. I also struggle now with sending an email from the site, it always times out, no matter what smtp provider I use (site's provider or Gmail).